# Hiding a button when maximum is reached: Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following button that is used to View More Friends in increments of 16:

```
<button class="cancel auto-btn hide-btn" id="viewAllFriends" style="display: visible;">View All Friends</button>
```

It's initial display is given with this:

```
var username = '<?php echo $username; ?>';
var num_friends = '<?php echo $num_friends; ?>';
var counter = 8;

$(document).ready(function(){

    <?php if ($num_friends > 8): ?>
    $("viewAllFriends").attr('style', 'display: visible;');

    $("#viewAllFriends").click(function(){
        counter = counter+16;

            $.ajax({

                url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{'username':username, 'num_friends':num_friends, 'counter':counter},

                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#data_friends').html(data);
                            }
                    });
            });
    <?php else: ?>   
        $("#viewAllFriends").attr('style', 'display: none;');
    <?php endif; ?>
});
```

The button displays if a user has more than 8 friends or does not if there is less than 8.  When `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` gets to the end, I have a hidden tag that echos on the page.

```
$max = "<p id='max' hidden>$num_rows</p>";
echo "$max";
```

The html output looks like this: `<p id="max" hidden="">43</p>`

This hidden tag doesn't appear on the page until the last query.  What I'm trying to do, is when 43 appears (which in this example indicates that there are no more friends to load) is remove the View More friends button from view.

This is what I've tried:

```
var friend_count = '<?php echo $num_friends; ?>';
var max = ("max").text();

if (max = friend_count) {
    $("#viewAllFriends").remove();

}
```

Sadly this isn't working - the button remains.  Everything else works fine, but this final detail.  I'm not so great at jQuery, so I'm wondering if the ajax is overriding this script, or if I'm possibly not getting the data in `var max`?  Any help, links, examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Where in your code do you have your `max` count and test (`if (max = friend_count) {`, etc)?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what `When ajax_load_profile_friends.php gets to the end, I have a hidden tag that echos on the page` means, exactly? How does the `max` element get added to the page?  Can you edit your question and show that code?

Comment: It's coming from `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` and now being echoed onto the page in last query with `$max = "<input id='max' type='hidden' value='$num_rows'>";`  `echo "$max";`  The html value on the page is displaying as 43.

Comment: So it is just part of the `data` passed to your AJAX success handler?

Comment: Yes.  It will complicate things to post all the code, but it evaluates correctly, and yes get's passed as part of the `data` in success handler.  It appears on the page ONLY in the last query which is an additional indicator that it's working correctly.  It's also displaying the correct number.  I just want to grab it and `hide()` the button somehow.

Comment: OK, and whereabouts do you have the code which checks the value of `max` and hides the button if needed?  I mean where does it fit in the code that you have shown?

Comment: I just did an `alert(max);` and I'm getting undefined.  For `alert(friend_count)` I'm getting 43.  So `var max = $("#max").val();` is not getting the 43.  And yet it's on the page displayed as `<input id="max" type="hidden" value="43">`

Comment: I'll ask one more time - whereabouts do you have the code which checks the value of max?

Comment: `max >= friend_count` I guess.  It's the only place that I'm using max, but I'm not grabbing the value from the input.

Comment: I've moved on to something else now, but I was asking (and you still haven't answered) where in the code you do that test.  It needs to be in your success callback, since `max` does not exist until the AJAX is finished.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you point me to something that could help me evaluate `max` then?  I think I understand what you're saying...sort of.  I just don't understand why when `max` does exist after the AJAX finishes, the script doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Hi @RichardSocker - not quite.  I have raised a new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879979/php-variables-not-returning-to-success-ajax-jquery-post-correctly-using-json-enc/54880010?noredirect=1#comment96531318_54880010) which shows more of the code.  I placed `<input id='max' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $num_rows; ?>'>` so the script always has something to evaluate.  However cannot get the `value` to update with AJAX success function.  Can you see something in `includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php ` with `json_encode` I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can try

```
$('#viewAllFriends').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

instead

$("#viewAllFriends").remove();

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work.  Same result - the button remains.

Comment: I thought it might be `display: visible` which is an error.  So I switched this to `display: block` then `display: none`.  But it's stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be like this.

First update ajax_load_profile_friends.php

```
$max = "<input id='max' type='hidden' value='".$num_rows."'>";
echo "$max";
```

Then in your script

```
var friend_count = '<?php echo $num_friends; ?>';
var max = $("#max").val();

if (max >= friend_count) {
    $("#viewAllFriends").hide();

}
```

Comment: The input is showing up on the page with a value of 43, so this works fine, but `#viewAllFriends` is still not hiding.