# PHP variables not returning to success AJAX/jQuery POST correctly using json_encode()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying for hours to get this to work.  I have a `<div id=""data_friends>` tag and a `hidden input field` that I want to update using AJAX.  The `div`tag is as follows:

```
<div class="friends-tab-list" id="data_friends">

    <?php 
    //Default query limits results to 8

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, friend_array) > 0 LIMIT 0,8");
    $query = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->get_result();

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['profile_pic']; 
        $row['username'];

        echo "<a class='profile-img-item' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
              <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
              </a>";
                }
        $query->close();

          ?>
</div>
```

The hidden input is as follows:  `<input id='max' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $num_rows; ?>'>`

I'm clicking on a View More Friends button and sending data to `includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php` using the following:

```
$.ajax({

    url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{'username':username, 'num_friends':num_friends, 'counter':counter},

        success: function(data) {
            $('#data_friends').html(data.html);
            $('#max').val(data.num_rows);
                }
        });
```

The data coming from ajax_load_profile_friends.php looks like this:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, friend_array) LIMIT $counter"); 
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->get_result();

$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
}       

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$row['profile_pic']; 
$row['username'];

$html = "<a class='profile-img-item' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
          <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
         </a>";

}   

echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows, 'html' => $html));
```

When I run this, I get a single return in my  when I'm suppose to get a return of 16 records with each click I thought by doing this in my success function `$('#data_friends').html(data.html);`
[image: View all friends button]

The value in my hidden input field `<input id='max' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $num_rows; ?>'>` is not updating using this `$('#max').val(data.num_rows);`

Is there something I'm missing in `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` that is causing these behaviors?

**Keep in mind that I can get this to work when I don't use `json_encode` & write success function like this `$('#data_friends').html(data.html);` and remove the `dataType: 'json',` from AJAX. The problem here is that in both ways, I'm not able to update my hidden input value.  I figured I would try and correct this method since most examples specify `json_encode()` as the way to return data.

Comment: When you use json_encode you get the num_rows null but the html is correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
header( "Content-Type: application/json", TRUE );
$query = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, friend_array) LIMIT $counter"); 
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->get_result();

$num_rows = $result->num_rows;

$html='';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$html .= "<a class='profile-img-item' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
          <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
         </a>";

}   

echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows, 'html' => $html));
```

Comment: When I concatenate `$html` as suggested the button does nothing.  No errors thrown or errors in console, just a button that does nothing.  When I remove `.=` and replace with `=` I get a single record returned.

Comment: what are getting when you run this console.log(data) ?

Comment: Without `.=` I'm getting on first click `num_rows: 24, html: "<a class='profile-img-item' href='la_fway'>…elion2.jpg' title='la_fway'>`  on second click I'm getting same thing, only `num_rows=40.`  So it is counting up, but only returning a single record.  When I use `.=` I get nothing.

Comment: also add header( "Content-Type: application/json", TRUE ); to top of your page , and declare $html as empty

Comment: what do you mean source code? , you are adding <?php at top, right?

Comment: yes of course - sorry put it on the wrong page.  It doesn't change the behavior though.  I did declare `$html = '';` before the `while loop` as suggested below - this now returns records when clicked but only up to 40.  I know there is 43 and at this point I have an alert that comes up.

Comment: what is your alert?

Comment: Just a bootstrap alert.  `No More Friends to Show`

Comment: Are you getting your result from ajax like you wanted?

Comment: I can get it to work without using json_encode, so will have to do. I can't for the life of me update the hidden input value which is only needed to hide() the View More Friends button. I guess it stays and the bootstrap alert can indicate when all friends are shown.

Comment: Is there a duplicate `id="max"` on the page?

Comment: @Barmar no there isn't.  I chose that b/c I knew it wouldn't be anywhere else.  Did a double check, it's the only `id="max"`

Comment: I'm really running out of ideas about what could be going wrong? Can I get access to your web page?

Comment: I wish b/c this is driving me nuts - usually I can troubleshoot something & get to it, but this has been ridiculous.  Unfortunately I'm working on this locally.

Comment: Then use the Network tab to see what's coming back in the full response, set breakpoints in the JavaScript code so you can examine the variables, etc. This is just basic debugging techniques, and should have all the debugging tools you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring $html variable before while loop. Try this one

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, friend_array) LIMIT $counter"); 
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->get_result();

$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
}       
$html = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
// $row['profile_pic']; 
// $row['username'];

$html .= "<a class='profile-img-item' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
          <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
         </a>";

}   

echo json_encode(array('num_rows' => $num_rows, 'html' => $html));
```

Comment: this way does something.  I'm getting to 40 records returning, but it won't display all 43.  The value in my hidden input field is still not updating. hmm...weird.

Comment: @Raylene What is the value of `counter`?

Comment: The counter begins at 8 - the initial query `num_rows`  for hidden input - `value='<?php echo $num_rows; ?>'`  I have it increasing with this: `$("#viewAllFriends").click(function(){ counter = counter+16;`  I echoed this on the page and it works.  I have this in the ajax page to evaluate for the final query:  `if($counter > $num_friends || $counter == $num_friends){ $counter = "No More Friends to Show";`  When I use the `json_encode` method however, it stops at 40 (there are 43 records).  My bootstrap alert doesn't show, b/c my `if` statement nvr evaluates to true.